# Adding field level javascript to pdf files using any language

Tags: python, pdf, itext, pdfbox, reportlab

I want to add field-level js to a particular field in a pdf file. So when the field is clicked an event should be triggered. Which is similar to adding a trigger in acrobat reader.

An easy example to understand: clicking a button in a pdf file to show or hide text in the same pdf. Is this possible?

I tried using several tools from Python. I was only able to find to add document level js, which is performing a js operation when pdf is opened.

But not able to add js field-wise. Any help.?

Comment: Package PyMuPDF supports this, see "date-field.py" and "interfield-calculation.py" in Github repo https://github.com/pymupdf/PyMuPDF-Utilities/tree/master/fields.

Comment: iText 7: `PdfWidgetAnnotation.setAdditionalAction(PdfName, PdfAction)`. PDFBox: `PDAnnotationWidget.setActions(PDAnnotationAdditionalActions)`.

Comment: PyMuPDF: just added a script that shows or hides a text field depending on some checkbox value: https://github.com/pymupdf/PyMuPDF-Utilities/blob/master/fields/switch-text-on-off.py.

Comment: Thanks for the comment @JorjMcKie. Is there any specfic version of PyMuPDF I should be using.?  Currently im using 1.21.1 (latest) but the script dont seem to work. I tried opening using Acrobat reader & chrome. The text field is visible all time. Even when checkbox is checked or unchecked.

Comment: @SaravananSb - sorry, I was too hasty: this is implemented in the version to come within the next days. Pls contact me via e-mail or the repo home page to get e pre-version wheel.